# I want to know how to calculate the jump instructions of a given virtual machine command in computer systems

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

I am learning about Hack Assembly Language and Jump Instructions. Could anyone please give me elaborate explanations of how you could calculate the jump instructions for a given virtual machine code. I would like to understand how to find the Jump Instructions if I had the Virtual Machine Command of, for example, push constant 0.

Please give me detailed explanations so I can learn!

Example: VIRTUAL MACHINE COMMAND is '`push constant 0`'.

How to get from THAT COMMAND to the following written JUMP INSTRUCTIONS:

```
@SP

A = M

M = 0

@SP

M=M+1
```

The jump instruction above is just an example, not the answer.

Comment: what instruction set?  And are those supposed to be instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Jumps are encoded in C-type instructions.

C-type instructions have the following encoding:

```
size (in bits):     1    2     7      3      3
                 +-----+----+------+------+------+
field            | A/C | XX | comp | dest | jump |
                 +-----+----+------+------+------+
```

To differentiate A-type and C-type, `A/C` is `0` for A-type and `A/C` is `1` for C-type.

If the `jump` field of a C-type instruction has the binary value `000`, then no jump is encoded.

Otherwise, any other binary value in the `jump` field encodes some kind of branch.  If the condition of the branch is true, it will transfer control to the value in the `A` register (effectively doing `pc := A`), so typically, a branching instruction is preceded by an `@` instruction to load the `A` register with the address of a label, but other approaches are possible.  If the condition of the branch is false, it will simply advance to the next sequential instruction (`pc := pc + 1` instead of `pc := A`)

---

See the following presentation: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/nand2tetris2/unit-0-4-hack-language-specification-MXyAQ, at time 7:57 for a table of the C-type instruction encodings.